# marketing Cloud Salesforce Data entry source - Filter Criteria not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

When i create a journey in Journey Builder and use "Salesforce Data" as entry source and select "filter criteria", the journey is not working when it meets the criteria. As far as i know and the description tells: If Entry Criteria are meet, the next step is looking at the Filter Criteria and if those are meet as well, the contact will enter the journey. By only filling out the Entry Criteria, the journey fires. What can be the reason that the journey is not firing when Entry Criteria are meet and Filter Criteria are meet?

Hopefully you guys can give me some more insights about the Filter Criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you would describe the data model and object relationship.

Otherwise, the possible issue is if you are trying to check One-To-Many type of a relationship through the Filter Criteria, while it can only work on One-To-One or Many-To-One.

- Example 1: You **cannot** use Person Account as main object (Entry) and check for Case object as Filter Criteria, because of Person Account can have many Cases and Journey Builder wouldn't know which one to check (no matter the Case Status or anything)
- Example 2: You **can** use Case (as Entry object) and use Person Account as Filter Criteria, since one Case (that passes Entry criteria) can only have one Person Account linked to it, therefore Journey Builder is able to check the attributes from it.

Comment: Indeed my entry object is the Person Account (contact). But the trigger of the journey is on the Person Account . How can i still use this field on the Person Account as a trigger?

Comment: Hi rain, can you still please help me with this matter?

Comment: Hey, in this case you do have 1-1 relationship, as one PersonAccount can have only one Contact. In this case you really shouldn't have any complications. Entry criteria is Account object -> you choose to inject PersonContactID -> you choose Filter Criteria under PersonContact (Contact) and fill out the rules you have. 
This way it should work fine.

Comment: As another note - keep in mind that Journey will track only the Entry Object to match criteria, not the Filter Criteria. Meaning if your main Object (PersonAccount) already matches criteria and the Contact record is updated to match the criteria, Journey will probably not fire. However if your Contact record matches the Filter Criteria and now you update the PersonAccount to match -> it should inject the Contact to Journey.

Comment: yeah i thought it would work like that. But still it's not firing when the "Contact" object is selected, entry event is for instance "email = bla@bla.com" and in filter criteria (which are related objects) i selected the object "Privacy Settings" and set the field "consent" to "Yes". Contact object is a 1-many relationship with the "Privacy Settings". can this be the problem?

Comment: Correct, this is the problem. As mentioned if you are using one-to-many objects during entry criteria check, then this "Privacy Settings" needs to be your Entry object, with the Contact related to the Privacy Settings record will be the Filter Criteria object. So just turn your Entry Criteria around.

Comment: Hi Rain, i tried that as well. It works, but it does not work, when i create a new record in the Contact object. My setup is: I have Privacy Settings object with Consent field as entry criteria, Filter criteria Contact object with Email field. Not working as well. is there a problem when creating new records?

Comment: Correct, when you are creating a Contact record (that matches criteria) then it will not fire the Journey. The trigger mechanism is always related to the Entry object -- meaning the Journey Builder will -only- check the related record (Contact in this case) if the PrivacySettings criteria is met. In scenario where PrivacySettings criteria is met and Contact is created after, it will not inject the Contact. One thing you can try out is making the link between PrivacySettings object and Contact to be required, this way it will fire the Journey only if you already have connected a Contact to it.

Comment: This sounds very logical. I think the approach here will be to run an automation based on a SQL query. thanks for your help Rain :)